# SELECT single row from child table for each row in parent table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get only one row from child table for each parent row with child fields included, I have been trying with GRUOP BY but with no success :(
Here is my initial SELECT

```
SELECT pID, lastname 
 FROM parent 
  LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT cID, pID, phone, company, title FROM child) as child 
   ON parent.pID = child.pID
```

Here is the tables strcture

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    pID Counter(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VarChar(24) DEFAULT '',
    lastname VarChar(20) DEFAULT ''
);

CREATE TABLE child (
    cID Counter(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    pID int DEFAULT '0',
    phone VarChar(16) DEFAULT '',
    company VarChar(24) DEFAULT '',
    title VarChar(24) DEFAULT '',
    address TEXT
);
```

Comment: What DB Engine are you using?

Comment: put the structure of your table and tell us more clearly what you really want

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*"get only one row from child table for each parent row with child fields included"*

That sounds like the `child` table can have more than one row for the same `pID` value.  And you want only one `child` row for each `pID`.

```
SELECT pID, Min(cID) AS MinOfcID
FROM child
GROUP BY pID;
```

Join that `GROUP BY` query back to the `child` table again to retrieve the other columns for each target `cID` value.  Save this query as `qryChild`.

```
SELECT
    c.pID,
    c.cID,
    c.phone,
    c.company,
    c.title,
    c.address
FROM
    (
        SELECT pID, Min(cID) AS MinOfcID
        FROM child
        GROUP BY pID
    ) AS map
    INNER JOIN child AS c
    ON c.cID = map.MinOfcID;
```

Finally, to include `lastname` values, join the `parent` table to `qryChild`.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is a standard ANSI solution:

```
SELECT pID, lastname 
FROM parent 
  LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT pID, 
                row_number() over (partition by pid order by cid) as rn
         FROM child
         ) as child 
         ON parent.pID = child.pID and child.rn = 1
```

Which rows you define as the "first" row is up to you. There is no such as a "first" row unless you sort the rows - that's what the part `order by cid` does in the partition clause. So if you want something different as the "first" row, you need to change that.

Btw: there is no need to select all columns from the child table if you don't use them.

Comment: MS Access doesn't support this JOIN clause!

Comment: @meYnot: MS Access is not an ANSI compliant DBMS. Please state your DBMS the next time. I wouldn't have answered if you had mentioned that right away

Comment: I am a beginner here and I did try to get more tags but I didn't recognize [ms-access] tho!

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to replace

```
SELECT cID, pID, phone, company, title FROM child
```

with something returning only one row per pid. What the correct choice is depends on your requriements. The simples is `group by`:

```
SELECT min(cID), pID, min(phone), min(company), min(title) FROM child group by cID
```

but the different columns will come from different rows so you probably want something like 'the first row' how to implement that depends on the RDBMS you are using, so please add that information to your question.

Comment: Thanks that works, but it doesn't accept Memo fields!


SELECT pID, parent.* FROM parent
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT min(cID), pID, min(phone), min(company), min(title), min(address) FROM child group by cID) AS child
ON parent.pID = child.pID

were [address] is memo field!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cID ChildID, 
       pID ParentID, 
       phone, 
       company, 
       title, 
       (SELECT lastname FROM parent WHERE id = ParentID) as LastName
FROM child
GROUP BY ParentID
```

Comment: Thanks Raheel, I am not familiar with access, while this seems perfect but its not working as ParentID is recognized even when adding [AS] to cid and pid in the 1st SELECT!

Comment: well the technique is that if you select something in the outer query you can use it in the sub query

Comment: Sorry i have changed Group by CID to PID that was my mistake check it again it will be perfect

Comment: Thanks Raheel, the error is in 
[(SELECT lastname FROM parent WHERE pID = ParentID) as LastName]
ParentID is unrecognized

Comment: I have modified the query you are right it should have been id not parent id in the sub query