# get only one row from products table for each category row with category name included

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables products and category. 1 category has many products. On the index page I just want to show only one latest product belonging to each category. in other words one product for one category.

Here is my table structure
Category table

[image: Category table]

product table
[image: Product table]

I have tried many answer but was unable to understand their answered queries. so plz recommend me query and also elaborate it if possible.

Comment: hint: use `HAVING` caluse. something like `HAVING MAX(date)`

Comment: i don't know why didn't it worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546444/get-only-one-row-from-products-table-for-each-category-row-with-category-name-in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479323/select-single-row-from-child-table-for-each-row-in-parent-table

Comment: I am a new bee. don't understand sql much

Comment: which DB? MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @DipenduPaul mysql in php server apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaahhhhhh after the hardwork of whole day i got it myself :)

```
SELECT category_id, product_name
FROM products
GROUP BY category_id
```

and it generates what i wanted, the following

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL JOINS. Something like this--

`SELECT cat.category_name,pro.sub_categories FROM Category AS cat INNER JOIN product AS pro ON cat.Id=pro.Id WHERE cat.Id=1`

Also before doin this make sure you have `category id` mentioned in your `products` table else the  `JOIN ON` condition wont work.

Comment: this generates this error: ""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=1' at line 1""

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0018 sec )

Answer (score 0):

since mysql does not support windowing functions i can only suggest this, hoping there are no two products with identical dates in the product_table. as i have no running mysql available, i am not sure this works.

```
select c.category_name
     , p.product_name
     , p.color
     , p.category_id
     , p.sub_categories
     , p.detail
     , p.[date]
     , p.[id]
     , p.bst_seller
     , p.size
  from products p
  join ( select category_id
              , max([date])
           from product_table
       ) d
    on p.[date] = d.[date]
  join category_table
    on p.category_id = c.[id]
```

---

**old version - only works with sql-server**

try using row_number windowing function to select the latest product per category and then join:

```
with products as (
    select product_name
         , color
         , category_id
         , sub_categories
         , detail
         , [date]
         , [id]
         , bst_seller
         , size
         , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by category_id order by date desc) as cand
      from product_table
)
select c.category_name
     , p.product_name
     , p.color
     , p.category_id
     , p.sub_categories
     , p.detail
     , p.[date]
     , p.[id]
     , p.bst_seller
     , p.size
  from products p
  join category_table c
    on p.category_id = c.id
 where p.cand = 1
```

Comment: this generates : ""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'with products as ( select product_name , color , catego' at line 1""" this error!

Comment: oh, since you used the sql-server tag, i thought you are using sql-server. windowing (the part where i use `over`) are not supported in mysql.

Comment: then what changes are required?

Comment: i just added a new version that will probably work in mysql, read my updated answer